# jQuery replace two div classes if they exist within a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel like I'm very close on this one but not quite. I'm not at all a genius at jQuery and CSS.

**My goal:** a dynamically building div within a table data cell for a calendar function. The input is determined from a date range. For full, scheduled days, I have a blue square (CSS). For a partial day, I create a triangular area dependant on morning or afternoon (again CSS). 

**The problem:** overlap of morning and afternoon.

What I've got thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/9hnNk/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/9hnNk/)

Can anyone tell what I'm missing here in my jQuery selector/replacement?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            morning:<br/>
            <div class="morning"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            afternoon:<br/>
            <div class="afternoon"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            split day:<br/>
            <div class="morning"></div>
            <div class="afternoon"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS:**

```
.morning{width:0;height:0;border-bottom:60px solid transparent;border-left:94px solid #0066CC;font-size:0;line-height:0;}
.afternoon{width: 0; height: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;border-top: 59px solid transparent;border-right: 95px solid #0066CC;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;}
.fullDay{border:30px;border-color:#0066CC;border-style:solid;height:0;width:32px;float:left;color:#FFFFFF;margin-left:2px;}
.splitDay{line-height:0%;width:0px;border-top:60px outset #0066CC;border-right: 100px dashed #0066CC;}
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
if ($("td:has(div.afternoon):has(div.morning)")){
    $(".morning").addClass('splitDay').removeClass('morning');
    $(".afternoon").remove();
    }
```

});

Comment: could just toggle class on row...then have rules for `.splitday .morning` and `.splitDay .afternoon` make your css adjustemts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your jQuery is that you are creating an entirely new selector with `$(".morning")` and `$(".afternoon")`, these will search through your entire html for divs with these classes. To find the correct ones you will want to save your if selector and use `.find` on it later like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $splitdays = $("td:has(div.afternoon):has(div.morning)");
    if ($splitdays) {
    $splitdays.find(".morning").addClass('splitDay').removeClass('morning');
    $splitdays.find(".afternoon").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah your pretty close, you are are checking to see if the case exists.  But you need to make sure you are only manipulating the rows that match your case.  To do this set the case elements to a variable and then by manipulating only that variable you are only modifying the `split day` elements instead of all the elements on your page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
if ($("td:has(div.afternoon):has(div.morning)")){
    var splitday = $("td:has(div.afternoon):has(div.morning)");

    splitday.find(".morning").addClass('splitDay').removeClass('morning');
    splitday.find(".afternoon").remove();
    }
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/9hnNk/4/

Comment: Both answers were correct. My apologies, I just went with the second one as it was the first I saw when coming back.